# Возрастающая последовательность Java

Tags: java

Как можно проверить, образуют ли цифры возрастающую последовательность?

Задание:
Написать консольную программу, определяющую, образуют ли цифры некоторого числа, строго возрастающую последовательность.
Например: 446 - не образуют, 789 - образуют.

```
public class Check {

    private static double getNumber(String string) {
        return Double.valueOf(string);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length == 1) {
            double number = getNumber(args[0]);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Input number");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: самое простое перевести число в строку и сравнивать по символам текущий со следующим. если отличие не 1 - значит не оно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский т.е. тогда метод getNumber не нужен, в число не переводить и просто пройтись по символам?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 139 образуют возрастающую последовательность, но отличие не на 1. Так что следующее больше предыдущего.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов  а, ну да. я просто пример 789 увидел и понеслось...)

Comment: @Nata ну да. в число не обязательно. т.к. это не алфавит и не сравниваются строки, то проблем со сравнением символов не должно быть.

Comment: Походу в комментарии нельзя переносы ставить. 
                String str = "124";
  boolean flag = true;
  Byte prevVal = null; 
  for(Byte val: str.getBytes()) {
   if (prevVal != null && prevVal >= val) {
    flag = false;
   }
   prevVal = val;
  }
  System.out.println(str);
  System.out.println(flag);

Comment: @Okdel напишите в ответе

Answer (score 4):

Сравнивать остатки при делении на 10

```
boolean testIncreasing(int AVal) {
  byte oldNum = 11;
  byte curNum = 10;
  while (AVal > 0 && curNum < oldNum) {
    oldNum = curNum;
    curNum = AVal % 10;
    AVal /= 10
  }
  return AVal == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно использовать и такое решение:

```
String numberString = Integer.toString(number);
return Stream.of(numberString.split(""))
        .distinct().sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.joining())
        .equals(numberString);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/V0Q7Uk

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {
  private static void check(String num) {
    for (int q=0; q<num.length(); ++q) {
      if (num.charAt(q) < '0' || num.charAt(q) > '9') {
        System.out.println("Invalid input: " + num);
        return;
      } else if (q > 0 && num.charAt(q) <= num.charAt(q-1)) {
        System.out.println("NO: " + num);
        return;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("YES: " + num);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    for (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); scanner.hasNextLine(); ) {
      check(scanner.nextLine());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ну и за что минус?

Comment: Мне бы не понравилось, что в ответ на вопрос от новичка, дается простыночка кода, без единого слова пояснения. Но я пройду мимо.